# How to see a repository folder's URL in the TortoiseSVN Windows shell integration / UI?

Tags: windows, url, svn, tortoisesvn, svn-repository

I can get the URL of a repo folder in Windows by right-clicking in/on the folder and selecting "TortoiseSVN | Copy URL to clipboard".

[image]

Is there a way to just *see* it instead of copying it?  I have to then open something and and paste it somewhere to see it, but I just want to see it right away, like in the UI somewhere.  It's not in "Properties" or anywhere else I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the folder properties, here you can see under the [Subversion](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-dia-1) page the URL on top:

[image]

Comment: Wow!  I never noticed that!  Thanks!